# NHibernate QueryOver Entity with IList properties sub property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-entities, linq-to-nhibernate

Having the following classes;

```
public class Customer{
  ....
  ....
  IList<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
}

public class Receipt{
  ....
  IList<SoldProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Having this said, my problem is that I'm trying to query the customer that has bought a specific product. When I try to execute the following code I get a NullReferenceException.

```
Customer c = null;
Receipt r = null;
SoldProduct sP = null;

var queryOver = Session.QueryOver(() => c)
    .JoinAlias(() => c.Receipts, () => r)
    .JoinAlias(() => r.SoldProducts, () => sP)
    .Where(() => c.Name.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           c.Surname.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           c.Address.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           c.Receipts.Select(receipt => 
                           receipt.SoldProducts.Select(product => product.Product.OldId.ToString()))
                           .SingleOrDefault().Single().IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

I'm just stuck right now. I might be missing a key point like here if so please let me know. If there is actually a easier way to execute this query I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Doesn't solved the problem, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply filter to product alias:

```
Customer c = null;
Receipt r = null;
SoldProduct sP = null;
Product p = null;

var queryOver = Session.QueryOver(() => c)
    .JoinAlias(() => c.Receipts, () => r)
    .JoinAlias(() => r.SoldProducts, () => sP)
    .JoinAlias(() => sp.Product, () => p)
    .Where(() => c.Name.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           c.Surname.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           c.Address.IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere) ||
                           p.OldId.ToString().IsLike(query.Search, MatchMode.Anywhere))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now I have the problem that the query doesn't work properly. When I query a product with its id inside the query.Search it doesn't returns that query. The problem seems to be with the p.OldId.ToString(), OldId is an int column and mapping converting it here to a string object just doesn't seem to be working. Do you have nay suggestions on this?